# Isolated point in spectrum

Tags: operator-theory

"Any isolated point in the spectrum of a self-adjoint operator must be an eigenvalue".

Is there an easy way to see this?

The spectral theorem tells us that any self-adjoint operator is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator in $L^2$ for suitable measure space. And I think unitary equivalence preserves the spectrum. So this reduces to studying isolated points in the spectrum of a multiplication operator...but does it help?

Comment: It is true more generally for a normal operator. The characteristic function $f=1_{\{\lambda\}}$ is continuous on the spectrum of $T$, so we can define $f(T)\neq 0$ by continuous functional calculus and $(T-\lambda Id)f(T)=0$. The claim follows.

Comment: A proof without using the spectral theorem can be found in http://www.ias.ac.in/mathsci/vol118/nov2008/PM00072.PDF (Theorem 4.1)

Comment: The link is broken. The reference is Proc. Indian Acad. Sci. (Math. Sci.) Vol. 118, No. 4, November 2008, pp. 613–625, https://web.archive.org/web/20211203131405/https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pmsc/118/04/0613-0625

Answer (score 3):

You may use the characterization of the spectrum set using spectral measure. 
A point on the complex plane belong to then spectrum if and only if any neibourhood of that  point has nonzero spectral measure. 
A point $\lambda$ on the complex plane is an eigenvalue if and only if the set $\{\lambda\}$ has nonzero spectral measure.
So your claim is correct.