# Spectrum of the Resolvent of a Self-Adjoint Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, and $A$ a self-adjoint operator with domain $D_{A} \subseteq \mathcal{H}$. Assume that $\lambda_0 \in \rho(A)$, where $\rho(A)$ is the resolvent set of $A$. For any $z \in \rho(A)$, let $R_{A}(z)=(A - z I)^{-1}$ be the resolvent of $A$.

Choose $\lambda \neq \lambda_0$. Then it is well known that $\lambda \in \rho(A)$ if and only if $(\lambda - \lambda_0)^{-1} \in \rho(R_{A}(\lambda_0))$ (see e.g. Schmudgen, Unbounded Self-adjoint operators on Hilbert Space, Proposition 2.10). So we have (note that by the spectral theorem $\sigma(A)$ is nonempty):
\begin{equation}
\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda_0)) \backslash \{0\} = \left \{ \frac{1}{\mu - \lambda_0} : \mu \in \sigma(A) \right \}.
\end{equation}
If $A$ is a bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$, then $0 \in \rho(R_{A}(\lambda_0))$, so that in this case, being $\sigma(A)$ closed, we have
\begin{equation}
\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda_0)) = \left \{ \frac{1}{\mu - \lambda_0} : \mu \in \sigma(A) \right \} = \text{closure}  \left \{ \frac{1}{\mu - \lambda_0} : \mu \in \sigma(A) \right \}.
\end{equation}
Now suppose that $A$ is unbounded. In this case $0 \in \sigma(R_{A}(\lambda_0))$. If we could prove that $0$ is not an isolated point of $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda_0))$ (which is the same to say that $\sigma(A)$ is not bounded), we could conclude also in this case that
 \begin{equation}
\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda_0)) =  \text{closure}  \left \{ \frac{1}{\mu - \lambda_0} : \mu \in \sigma(A) \right \}.
\end{equation}
So my question is the following: if $A$ is unbounded, can $\sigma(A)$ be bounded?

PS This question arouse from the answer given by TrialAndError in this post 
[Norm of the Resolvent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855151/norm-of-the-resolvent)

Comment: What is $R_A(\lambda_0)$? Is it $(A-\lambda_0)^{-1}$? I think you also have a typo in your first paragraph. Should it be $(\lambda-\lambda_0)^{-1}$?

Comment: $R_A(\mu)$ is usually the inverse of $\mu I - A$

Comment: This question might be of interest to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194681/does-an-unbounded-operator-t-with-non-empty-spectrum-have-an-unbounded-spectru

Comment: Dear Cameron, the last answer to the post you quoted is actually related to the argument given by TrialAndError in one of his comments http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855151/norm-of-the-resolvent He actually says that for any normal operator $N$ with a bounded spectrum , we have $ N = - \frac{1}{2 \pi i}  \int_{C_{R}} \lambda R_{N}( \lambda) d \lambda $, where $C_R=\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C}: |\lambda| = R \}$, and $R > 0$ is big enough so that $C_R$ encircles the spectrum of $N$. But I can't see how to prove this representation

Comment: If we denote by  $\mathcal{B(H)}$ the Banach space of bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$, then $R_{N}: \rho(N) \rightarrow \mathcal{B(H)}$ is an analytic function. So the integral $\oint_{C_R} \lambda R_{N}(\lambda) d \lambda$ is well defined and by definition is in $\mathcal{B(H)}$. So if we could prove the above representation for $N$, then we could conclude that $N$ cannot be unbounded if it has a bounded spectrum.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that an isolated point of the spectrum for a normal operator is an eigenvalue? Is that something that has been proved at the level at which you're trying to work?

Comment: @CameronWilliams : One of the comments to the post you reference explains how to construct an unbounded operator $T$ with $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$ as a direct sum of $0$ and of an operator with empty spectrum. That's a legitimate example of an unbounded operator with non-empty bounded spectrum. However, normal operators are different. Normal operators with bounded spectrum must be bounded.

Comment: @TrialAndError: No, I could not prove that an isolated point of the spectrum of a normal operator is an eigenvalue, otherwise it would be evident to me that $0$ cannot be an isolated of spectrum of $R_{A}(\lambda)$ if $A$ is unbounded, being $R_{A}(\lambda)$ normal. I see that a proof has been given in a comment to the post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553013/isolated-point-in-spectrum Anyway, I don't know functional calculus.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Is it a difficult task to establish the representation $N = - \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C_R} \lambda R_{N}(\lambda) d \lambda $ you suggested for a normal operator with boundes spectrum? I know something about analytic functions taking values in complex Banach spaces. This equation reminds me the residue theorem, but I have no idea of how to prove it.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I have corrected the editing errors in the question. Thank you very much for having kindly made me notice them and for having drawn my attention to the interesting post you referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $r > \max \sigma(A)$.  Then $R_A(r)$ is self-adjoint and bounded.  If $0$ is not in its spectrum, then $A = (R_A(r)^{-1}+rI$ is bounded.  If $0$ is in its spectrum, it is an isolated point of the spectrum and therefore must be an eigenvalue: $R_A v = 0$ for some $v \in \mathcal H$.  But that is impossible since $R_A(r) = (A-rI)^{-1}$, i.e. $R_A(r) v = u$ where $u \in D_A$ and $(A-rI) u = v$.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned you like Complex Analysis. So I thought I'd offer a proof using Complex Analysis applied to the resolvent. The proof comes down to evaluating the integral around all finite singularities of $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x$ by determining the residue at $\infty$, which turns out to be $x$. This equivalence forces the completeness of spectral expansions for normal operators. It's a type of Complex Analysis conservation law that allows you to expand $x$ in terms of integrals in the finite plane. If the singularities are all discrete in the finite plane, you end up with an eigenfunction expansion of $x$. Continuous spectrum can lead to integral expansions, such as the classical Fourier integral expansions. More generally, the Spectral Theorem for sefadjoint operators can be proved using this conversation law; completeness is established by knowing that the resiude at infinity of $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ is $I$. So the technique is worth learning.

Suppose $A$ is a closed densely-defined normal operator on a Complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and suppose that $\sigma(A)$ is a bounded set. By the previous problem you referenced,
$$
     \|(\lambda I -A)^{-1}\| \le \frac{1}{\mbox{dist}(\lambda,\sigma(A))}.
$$
Therefore, $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}
(\lambda I-A)^{-1}=0$, and, for a fixed $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$, the following limit is uniform in $\lambda$:
$$
  \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}x+(\lambda I-A)^{-1}Ax = x.
$$
If $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$, and if $R$ is large enough that $\sigma(A)\subseteq \{ \lambda : |\lambda| < R \}$, then 
$$
    \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\lambda|=R}(\lambda I-A)^{-1}xd\lambda
   = \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\lambda|=R}\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda}=x.
$$
Because $\mathcal{D}(A)$ is dense and $\oint_{|\lambda|=R}(\lambda I-A)^{-1}d\lambda$ is a bounded operator, then
$$
      \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\lambda|=R}(\lambda I-A)^{-1}d\lambda =I.
$$
For $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$,
\begin{align}
    Ax & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\lambda|=R}(\lambda I-A)^{-1}Ax\,d\lambda \\
       & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\lambda|=R}-x+\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x\,d\lambda \\
       & = \left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\lambda|=R}\lambda (\lambda I-A)^{-1}d\lambda\right)x
\end{align}
So $A$ is bounded on $\mathcal{D}(A)$, which also forces $\mathcal{D}(A)=\mathcal{H}$ because $A$ is closed.